# how to mock a specific implementation of a protocol?

Tags: clojure, mocking, protocols

How to mock a specific implementation of a protocol, preferably with plain Clojure i.e. no external libs e.g. Midje? I know how to mock **all** implementations but not specific ones:

```
(defprotocol P
  (foo [p]))
(defrecord R1 [])
(defrecord R2 [])
(extend-protocol P
  R1
  (foo [_] :r1)
  R2
  (foo [_] :r2))

(foo (->R1)) ;; :r1
(foo (->R2)) ;; :r2

;; now the mocking ...
(with-redefs [foo (constantly :redefed)]
  (println (foo (->R1)))  ;; :redefed
  (println (foo (->R2)))) ;; :redefed
```

i.e. how to get `(foo (->R1))` to return `:redefed` while `(foo (->R2))` still returns `:r2`?

Assume I can only make changes below the `now the mocking ...` comment. Notice that I am putting aside the recommendation to extend a protocol only if I have control of the protocol, the type, or both.

Comment: So you have no control over `P`, `R1`, `R2`, or `foo` (everything above the "now the mocking..." comment)?

Comment: let's say I don't ...

Comment: Unclear. Are you writing the `extend-protocol` part?

Comment: no - let's say the only thing I have control over is the mocking portion i.e. I can make changes only below the `now the mocking ...` comment. I hope that clarifies it.

Comment: Your constraints are becoming unreasonable. You don't control the protocol, or the code using the protocol, or the code constructing instances of objects implementing the protocol, or the code calling methods on protocol instances. Of course you can't change anything if you don't control anything. Clojure does not support arbitrary monkey-patching. You've received two answers so far saying "you could do X", to which you respond "well actually X is impossible for me". Try defining your goals at a higher level so someone can help you reach them.

Comment: @amalloy, while I appreciate and find the suggested design alternatives useful, my original question is about whether it is possible (and if so, how) to mock one implementation and not others given the constraints. Maybe the answer is that it is not possible which would be a perfectly valid answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new protocol containing methods with the same signature and use that when rebinding:

```
(def foo-orig foo)

(defprotocol Q
  (bar [q]))
(extend-protocol Q
  R1
  (bar [_] :redefed)
  R2
  (bar [this] (foo-orig this)))
```

Note you'll have to capture the original `foo` definition for the implementations you don't want to change. Then:

```
(with-redefs [foo bar]
              (println (foo (->R1)))   ;; :redefed
              (println (foo (->R2))))  ;; :r2
```

or you could defined a multimethod e.g.

```
(defmulti bar (fn [q] (type q)))
(defmethod bar R1 [_]
  :redefed)
(defmethod bar :default [q]
  (foo-orig q))
```

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is to have the `foo` impls delegate to a helper fn:

```
(extend-protocol P
  R1
  (foo [p] (foo-r1 p))
  R2
  (foo [p] (foo-r2 p)))
```

with

```
(defn foo-r1 [_] :r1)
(defn foo-r2 [_] :r2)
```

and then just redef `foo-r1` and `foo-r2` independently as desired.

Note also that `with-redefs` is meant to operate on `var` instances, while the `foo` you define as part of a protocol is not the same as a `var`. That may be the cause of your global redefinition problem.

---

### Update

You may need to clarify your use-case & update the question.  See [this part at clojure.org](https://clojure.org/reference/protocols#_extend_only_things_you_control):

> Extend only things you control You should extend a protocol to a type
>   only if you control the type, the protocol, or both. This is
>   particularly important for the protocols included with Clojure itself.

Comment: Thanks - now, what if I have no control over the original implementations? I will update the question to add that limitation

Comment: agreed on the best practice for extending protocol - the question was updated to reflect awareness of it. Putting that aside, the question still stands.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easiest to define wrapper functions for protocol internal implementation functions and call them from outside.
Then it can be mocked easily with `with-redefs` et al.
It also has other benefits, e.g. being able to define specs for such functions.

Comment: _being able to define specs for such functions_ is it not possible to define specs for protocol implementations?

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass `foo` an R1 at all. Define a new implementation, R1Mocked, that does whatever you want, and pass that instead. This is exactly the sort of polymorphism that protocols are designed to support.

Comment: _Don't pass foo an R1 at all_. The intent is to continue to pass an `R1` into `foo` while modifying the behavior. Let me rephrase the question to make it clear that the intent is to modify the behavior of the call `(foo (->R1))` without impacting the behavior of the call `(foo (->R2))` without altering the calls themselves.